# Problem with associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have always sucked at complex arrays there must be something in my brain preventing me from ever understanding them.  I will try to make this example really simple so we will not go off topic.  I use this code to use numbers to represent each file name:

```
$mod_nums = array('1' => $input_zip_path . '01_mod_1.0.2.zip',

                  '2' => $input_zip_path . '02_mod_1.0.1.zip',
);
```

So when I use $mod_nums['01'] it will display the path to that file.  I have an array from the script that put these $mod_nums values into an array like so:

```
$files_to_zip = array(
    $mod_nums['1'],
    $mod_nums['2']
);
```

That worked fine.  Now I wanted to add a $_POST value so that I can enter numbers like 1,2 and other numbers that I add to the $mod_nums array later like 1,3,6,12 for example.  So I used an explode for those posted values:

```
$explode_mods  = explode(",", trim($_POST['mods']));
```

Now for the big question that is racking my brain and spent hours on and cannot get it to work.... I need for $files_to_zip to still be in an array and display the posted values of $mod_nums.  So it would be like:

```
$files_to_zip = array( HAVE $_POSTED VALUES IN HERE );
```

I hope that makes sense.  I need $files_to_zip to remain in array format, grab the file path to the zip files from the $mod_nums array, and display it all correctly so it would dynamically output:

$files_to_zip = array('01_mod_1.0.2.zip', '02_mod_1.0.1.zip');

so posted numbers will appear in an array format for the $files_to_zip variable.  Make sense? In short I need an array to have dynamic values. Thanks :)

EDIT

Phew I figured it out myself from memory when I worked on something similar many years ago. This looks tough but it isn't.  I had to use a foreach and assign the variable into an array like so:

```
$blah = array();

foreach ($explode_mods as $value)
{
    $blah[] = $mod_nums[$value];
}
```

then I just assigned $files_to_zip to $blah:

```
$files_to_zip = $blah;
```

works perfectly :)  I just forgot how to dynamically assign values into an array.

Comment: I have seen other script use this a lot.  Basically dynamic values into an array from a $_POST field where the values are separated by commas in a string is what I need.

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't very clear. What kind of value does `$_POST['mods']` contain? You've already defined `$files_to_zip` as an array, so why do you need to change anything? I'm guessing what you actually want to do is loop through the POST data using foreach. Can't say without further information.

Comment: I have a feeling you're asking about something very basic in a very compilacted way. give a simple example: what's in $_POST['mods'] and what do you want to create?

Comment: YES I FIGURED IT OUT MYSELF FROM MEMORY!!! IT IS SIMPLE!  I Will edit my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// filenames array
$mod_nums = array('1' => $input_zip_path . '01_mod_1.0.2.zip',
                  '2' => $input_zip_path . '02_mod_1.0.1.zip',
);

// mod_num keys
$explode_mods  = explode(',', trim($_POST['mods']));

// array to hold filenames
$files_to_zip = array();

// loop over all the mod_num keys submitted via POST
foreach($explode_mods as $key){
    // save the filename to the corresponding array
    $files_to_zip[] = $mod_nums[$key];
}
```

Comment: Haha yes you guys answered it correctly after I figured it out, but good job for understanding :)

Comment: @John Jenkins: It's great that you figured it out yourself already. That way you will almost never forget it again. Feel free to accept an answer now by clicking on the empty tick below the vote count on the top left hand side of the answer, so this question gets marked as resolved. For more details see [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanks :)  I chose your answer, did I complete this question correctly?

Comment: @John Jenkins: Yes, your issue has been resolved. Our answers are like the one you already found out yourself, so, if it worked for you, it will work for others, too. The question has been marked resolved, good luck with your coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe i havn't understood you right, but won't this just be a simple foreach-loop to add the entrys to `$files_to_zip` like this:

```
$explode_mods  = explode(",", trim($_POST['mods']));

foreach($explode_mods as $k){
    $files_to_zip[] = $mod_nums[$k];
}
```

Comment: Haha yes you guys answered it correctly after I figured it out, but good job for understanding :)